# recursivly determine if there is a subset sum of a positive int array that matches a given int argument?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

the solution should be recursive ,zero is an element of any set, and the catch is that you can use an element of the set multiple times.

for example if the array is {3,5,7} so 17 will return true because 5+5+7=17
but 4 will return false.

i have tried this:

```
public static boolean isSumOf(int [] s, int n)
{
        return isSumOf(s, s.length, n);
}
static boolean isSumOf(int s[], int length, int n)
{
   // Base Cases
   if (n == 0)
   {
       return true;
   }

   if (length == 0 && n != 0)
   {
       return false;
   }

   // If last element is greater than sum, then ignore it
   if (s[length-1] > n)
   {
       return isSumOf(s, length-1, n);
   }


   /* else, check if sum can be obtained by any of the following
      (a) including the last element
      (b) excluding the last element   */
   return isSumOf(s, length-1, n) || isSumOf(s, length-1, n-s[length-1]);
}
```

but it excludes the ability to add elements multiple times

Answer (score 2):

Don't shorten array, just walk through all values in the loop like this:

```
//base cases
...
res = false;
for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    if (s[i]<= n)
        res = res ||  isSumOf(s[], length, n - s[i]);
return res;
```

If loops are not allowed, call recursion with and without the last element (note I removed `-1` in the second call):

```
return isSumOf(s, length-1, n) || isSumOf(s, length, n-s[length-1]);
```

Comment: i forgot to say that i am not allowed to use loops but its an interesting direction...

Comment: wow i can't believe that!! i'm trying to solve this for hours... thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static boolean isSumOf(int s[], int length, int n) {
   if (n == 0)
       return true;
   if (length == 0)
       return false;
   int last = s[length - 1];
   if (last > n)
       return isSumOf(s, length - 1, n);
   return isSumOf(s, length - 1, n)
       || isSumOf(s, length - 1, n - last)
       || isSumOf(s, length, n - last);
}
```

result

```
int[] array = {3, 5, 7};
int length = array.length;
System.out.println(isSumOf(array, length, 12));  // true
System.out.println(isSumOf(array, length, 5));   // true
System.out.println(isSumOf(array, length, 8));   // true
System.out.println(isSumOf(array, length, 25));  // true
System.out.println(isSumOf(array, length, 4));   // false
```

Comment: @SanketMakani Sorry, I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is more of the standard subset sum, where the repeating of elements is not allowed during sum operation.

But your requirement allows repeating elements.

> for example if the array is {3,5,7} so 17 will return true because 5+5+7=17 but 4 will return false.

That's why you are not getting the results. As pointed by MBo checking for all elements during sum calculation helps.

**Note:** If the requirement is to find all such combinations then it is more like a [coin exchange problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/)

Hope it helps!